# Gatsby / GraphQL - Sourcing data from external API. Setup gatsby-node.js but SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

Tags: graphql, fetch, gatsby

Trying to source data from API in order to querying that data from gatsby and display it, but ‍️

gatsby develop

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
```

when:

./gatsby-node.js

```
sync function fetchWinesAndTurnIntoNodes() {
    const res = await fetch('https://api.sampleapis.com/wines/reds');
    const wines = await res.json();
    console.log(wines)
}



export async function sourceNodes(params) {
    await Promise.all([await fetchWinesAndTurnIntoNodes(params)]);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> "The command we want to run is called gatsby build. But because we want to use es modules with gatsby, we use a package called esm. One way to require it is to set the NODE_OPTIONS environmental variable to -r esm. Finally to make this work for windows users, we use the cross-env package. Hopefully once Node es modules are stable, we can bring this back to simple gatsby build" Wes Bos.

So, install

```
npm i esm -D
npm i cross-env -D
```

then add to scripts at
./package.json

```
"start": "cross-env NODE_OPTIONS=\"-r esm\" gatsby develop",
"build": "cross-env NODE_OPTIONS=\"-r esm\" gatsby build",
```

solved!